# Table environment just printing position specifier

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, overleaf

I'm writing a scientific paper on overleaf, and have a couple of tables in an appendix. I'm trying to specify the tables should be `[h]` in the text using `\begin{table}[h]` but it's (a) not printing the table in the correct place and (b) printing the characters `[h]` literally in the document. MVE and screenshot included.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \toprule
    Coefficient & Value           \\ \midrule
    $c_A$       & $0.65 \pm 0.05$ \\
    $c_0$       & $-4.7 \pm 0.5$  \\
    $c_1$       & $0.72 \pm 0.05$ \\
    $c_2$       & $-4.9 \pm 0.2$  \\
    $c_3$       & $29 \pm 2$      \\
    $c_4$       & $-38 \pm 4$     \\
    $b_0$       & $0.9 \pm 0.5$   \\
    $b_1$       & $-13.6 \pm 0.1$ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table of model coefficients used in Equations \ref{eq:angus1} \& \ref{eq:angus2} as defined in \citet{Angus2019}.}
    \label{table:angus}
\end{table}
```

Any ideas as to if there's a package doing something odd, or if the scientific journal template defined [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/monthly-notices-of-the-royal-astronomical-society-mnras-latex-template-and-guide-for-authors/kqnjzrwjwjth) is doing something odd?

p.s. First post here, let me know if anything should be clearer! Thanks.

[image: screenshot of table weirdness]

Comment: Do you get errors (red circle in overleaf) as shown in the log file If you get _any_ error the output pdf is not intended to be usable, Your description would suggest that the class you are using does not define a `table` environment, but that would give an undefined environment error.

Comment: I just looked and the journal, guidelines explicitly say not tp worry about table positioning as it will be handled by the journal software later. the template you link to says: \subsection{Figures and tables}

Figures and tables should be placed at logical positions in the text. Don't
worry about the exact layout, which will be handled by the publishers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no errors no. I guess you're right, I'll leave it for the publishers to sort out and leave it floating for now.

Comment: Off-topic: If your documents display equation numbers surrounded by parentheses, you may want to change `Equations \ref{eq:angus1} \& \eqref{eq:angus2}` to `Equations \ref{eq:angus1} \& \eqref{eq:angus2}`. (The `\eqref` macro is defined in the `amsmath` package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You employ the `mnras` document class, right? Here's an excerpt from section 8.2, "Captions and placement [of `figure` and `table` floats]", of the user guide of the MNRAS class:

> The LATEX float placement commands `[htbp]` are intentionally disabled.

In short, don't use `[h]` -- or any other placement specifier, for that matter -- when creating floats with this document class.

The very same section from which the excerpt shown above was lifted also contains the following directive:

> Captions go *above* tables but *below* figures.

[emphasis in the original]

You may therefore want to adjust where the `\caption` directive occurs within the `table` float.

---

*Addendum*: Since the table's cells almost all either mathematical symbols or numbers, you may want to employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. You may also want to arrange the numbers so that they're lined up on their explicit or implicit decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\renewcommand\theequation{B\arabic{equation}} % just for this example
\renewcommand\thetable{B\arabic{table}}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}  % optional
\newcommand\crefpairconjunction{~\& }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\centering
    \caption{Model coefficients used in \cref{eq:angus1,eq:angus2} 
    as defined in \citet{Angus2019}.}
    \label{table:angus}
    $\begin{array}{ c @{\quad} d{3.2} @{{}\pm{}} d{1.2} }
    \toprule
    \text{Coefficient} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Value}} \\ 
    \midrule
    c_{\mkern-2mu A} & 0.65 & 0.05 \\
    c_0 & -4.7  & 0.5  \\
    c_1 & 0.72  & 0.05 \\
    c_2 & -4.9  & 0.2  \\
    c_3 & 29    & 2    \\
    c_4 & -38   & 4    \\
    b_0 & 0.9   & 0.5  \\
    b_1 & -13.6 & 0.1  \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{array}$
\end{table}

\begin{gather} % define two dummy equations
  1+1=2 \label{eq:angus1} \\ 
  0+0=0 \label{eq:angus2}
\end{gather}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Angus et al.(2019)]{Angus2019} Angus \dots

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for such a detailed answer. You're correct on the template, and I'll bear in mind on the array environment over table.